# Remove specific query parameters from URL in Nginx

Tags: nginx, filter, url-rewriting

I have a url which is similar to below

http://www.example.com/index.html?jeff=345kol&remove=ab67&test=tester123&ignore=78ujy

I want to remove "&remove" and "&ignore" arguments from the url and after removing its should like as below

http://www.example.com/index.html?jeff=345kol&test=tester123

Is it possible to implement it in Nginx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), each argument is accessible via special attribute, for instance: $arg_jeff, $arg_remove:

```
location = /index.html {
  rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/index.html$is_args$arg_jeff&arg_test;
}
```